# MA 2015 Schedule Z line 12: "Income tax paid to another state or jurisdiction (from worksheet)" -> what worksheet are they talking about?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-credit, massachusetts

I am filling out a [2015 Schedule Z](https://www.mass.gov/lists/2015-massachusetts-personal-income-tax-forms-and-instructions) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181219215139/https://www.mass.gov/files/documents/2017/12/04/dor-2015-inc-sch-zrf.pdf)) in Massachusetts, USA, which I plan to attach to a [2015 Form 1](https://www.mass.gov/lists/2015-massachusetts-personal-income-tax-forms-and-instructions) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180919085428/https://www.mass.gov/files/documents/2017/12/04/dor-2015-inc-form-1_0.pdf)).

Line 12 says: "Income tax paid to another state or jurisdiction (from worksheet)".  What worksheet are they talking about?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's on page 21 (page 33 of the PDF) of the [Form 1 instructions](https://www.mass.gov/doc/2015-form-1-instructions/download):

[image]